# Error showing underneath function when trying to do a async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i try and do an "async function" i always get an error underneath "function", see below with the comment where the error is:

```
function sleep(ms) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {  // function reports as an error
   document.writeln('2...');
   await sleep(2000);
   document.writeln('3...');
}

document.writeln('1...');
   demo().then(() => {
   document.writeln('4.');
});
```

I am using Eclipse Oxygen ("Eclipse IDE for Javascript and Web Developers")

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: What's the full text of the error?

Comment: Unfortunately it just says "No suggestions available". The error is a red jagged line under "Function"

Comment: It turns out this is a known bug in Eclipse - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545216